# Align a picture partly outside a cell

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx,ltxtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}


\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline

Imperfetto & Imperfetto & Imperfetto & Imperfetto & O3 & 81 & 27 & 9 & 3 & 1 \\

\hline

\multicolumn{10}{|c|}{}  \\[0.5ex]

\multicolumn{10}{|@{\hskip0pt}l@{\hskip0pt}|}{\raisebox{-2ex}{\includegraphics[scale=1.12]{esempiotabellamodi.pdf}}}  \\


\end{tabular}

}


\end{document}
```

I would like to align the bottom line of my picture to the end of the vertical lines of its cell.

[image: Align a picture partly outside a cell]

Thanks for any help,
J

Comment: note you have white space  to the left and right of your table, use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {%` and similarly don't leave space at the end. To lower the music use `\raisebox{-xxpt}{\includegraphics{...}`

Comment: Without having the included image at hand this is difficult, in my point of view, given some white space etc. ? You're including some unneeded packages as well

Comment: \raisebox didn't work, there's white space in the picture below the last line, because some notes have a stem which exceeds the bottom line. I don't know how to include my picture as a pdf here... Some packages are needed for other parts of my work, that's why they're there.

Comment: you can use the optional argument to raisebox to hide the  depth so teh table rules do not extend.

Comment: It works!!!!\multicolumn{10}{|@{\hskip0pt}l@{\hskip0pt}|}{\raisebox{-10pt}[0ex][1.6ex]{\includegraphics[scale=1.12]{esempiotabellamodi.pdf}}}  \\

Comment: They may be needed in your document, but they are not needed in the ***minimal***  example you post here ;).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional argument to `\raisebox` to hide the depth so the table rules do not extend.

```
\multicolumn{10}{|@{}l@{}|}{%
  \rais‌​ebox{-10pt}[0ex][1.6‌​ex]{%
     \includegraphics‌​[scale=1.12]{esempio‌tabellamodi.pdf}}}\\
```